# Wait for all components to be loaded before rendering pdf

Tags: swift

I try to render my view as pdf but I added a MapView and the problem is that the rendering don't wait the map to load. Is there a way the render can wait and show the location of the map I wanted ?

```swift
    let pdfRenderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        do {
            try pdfRenderer.writePDF(to: outputFileURL, withActions: { (context) in
                context.beginPage()
                rootVC?.view.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
            })
            print("wrote file to: \(outputFileURL.path)")
        } catch {
            print("Could not create PDF file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can render you PDF inside didUpdateLocations method

Comment: Yes you're totally right, but I was wondering if there was a method to wait, otherwise I will do that

Comment: It is an asynchronous method I don’t think you have an alternative